# ROS 2 Params YAML File Package-Relative Path

Tags: ros, yaml, rosparam, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there currently any analog to the `rosparam` flag `subst_value` for ROS 2 YAML parameter files? I would like to use a package-relative path (like `$(find package_name)/path/to/file.txt` from ROS 1) in a ROS 2 parameters file but I can't find an example of this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348600/ros-2-params-yaml-file-package-relative-path/) by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1766 on 2020-04-06

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-11-05**:
@dirk-thomas, @william, or @tfoote Several people have asked me about this. Would you mind weighing in?

**Comment by [Divyanshu](https://answers.ros.org/users/63683/divyanshu/) on 2020-11-25**:
I am facing a similar issue, it would be great if someone could answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This PR added that capability to ROS2.

https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/pull/168#issuecomment-715587364

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2021-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-12-20**:
Thanks for the pointer!